# New to electronics in general, are these two LiPo batteries identical?

Tags: power, battery, tutorial

I just received my first raspberry pi zero as a birthday present and thought the PiGrrl Zero by Adafruit would be a fun first project. I've got the kit, but it didn't come with the LiPo battery. I live in the UK and it seems silly to ship [the battery Adafruit stocks](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2011) when surely I could just get an identical spec'd battery here?

[This is what I've found that I could get in short order](https://www.coolcomponents.co.uk/lithium-polymer-battery-2000mah.html). It appears identical to me, but I lack confidence. Is there something I'm missing? Also, is there a better deal I'm missing out on?

I really appreciate the help and advice. Apologies if this is too low level a question for this forum, I'll happily delete and move elsewhere if this is the case. I just don't want to blow up my pi!

Thanks and all the best.

Answer (score 1):

They are both single cell 3.7v 2000mAh batteries - they are effectively identical as far as power is concerned. They might be slightly different shape but that is all.

Also, any 3.7v single cell lipo battery will work in its place, the capacity (mAh) will affect how long it will last for before needing to be recharged. You can opt for a larger battery if you require the project to run for longer, or smaller battery if you want a cheaper/smaller form factor.